Issue with proxy using RTK query and vite
I am starting to use Vite instead of CRA but I can't get the proxy to work.
I am using json server for my database and it is located at http://localhost:3000/customers
With CRA, I'd add "proxy": "http://localhost:3000", to package.json and then in my apiSlice:
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "" });

However this isn't working with Vite, so I tried adding this instead to vite.config:
server: {
        proxy: {
            "/api": "http://localhost:3000",
        },
    },

and changed my baseQuery to:
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "/api" });

However I keep getting this error in the console:
CustomerList.jsx:4 Uncaught TypeError: useGetCustomersQuery is not a function or its return value is not iterable

useGetCustomersQuery is my RTK query, I believe the issue is that is is not communicating with the backend as it should.

No, your problem is that useGetCustomersQuery is not set. This has nothing to do with data fetching.
You probably imported createApi from @reduxjs/toolkit/query and not from @reduxjs/toolkit/query/react.

Hey thanks, I hope that is the case, I do have the correct import but I will investigate further what you said.

Would this make it a duplicate of this or this or a few others?

Nah, Master was right, I messed up elsewhere, by the way proxy in package.json works fine
